# How to put/get multiple entities at once in Google cloud Datastore using java

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

In the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Retrieving_an_entity), I didn't find how I can put or retrieve multiple entities at once. further, by using GQL, I was not able to execute queries such select * from k where __ key __ in ('key1','key2','key3').

Can any one help me please, how I can insert/ retrieve multiple entities at once using java??

Thanks,

Comment: I'm not experienced with google-cloud-datastore, but I know with `Google Drive's Java SDK`, it is NOT possible to upload multiple documents at once, but it is possible to query for files, and this DOES give a List of zero or more files it found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Cloud Datastore, a `LookupRequest` and `CommitRequest` allow multiple keys and entities, respectively, to be specified. For example:

```
LookupRequest request = LookupRequest.newBuilder()
    .addKey(key1)
    .addKey(key2)
    .build();
```

or:

```
CommitRequest request = CommitRequest.newBuilder()
    .setMode(CommitRequest.Mode.NON_TRANSACTIONAL)
    .setMutation(Mutation.newBuilder()
        .addInsert(entity1)
        .addInsert(entity2))
    .build();
```

These are slight variations on the examples given on these pages:
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Retrieving_an_entity
https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities#Datastore_Creating_an_entity

Cloud Datastore GQL does not currently support `IN` or writes.

Comment: Thanks, it works.But, I'd like to know What is the max. number of keys that I can retrieves or entities that I can put?? when I tried 10, It doesn't work!!

Answer (score 0):

Although your question uses GQL, it is tagged java, so I'll give you two answers for the price of one.

You can use `get(Iterable<Key>)` and `put(Iterable<Entity>)` in the `DatastoreService` to get and put multiple entities at once.  The [javadocs](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/datastore/DatastoreService) provide a useful reference.

If you want to use GQL in the [datastore viewer](http://appengine.google.com), you'll need to do so like this

```
SELECT * FROM Kind where __key__ in (key('Kind', id1), key('Kind', id2), ...)
```

Comment: Your answer refers to the Google App Engine datastore API, however the question is referring to the Cloud Datastore API.

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve multiple entities by specifying their keys, you should use GetMulti instead of writing a query.
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/reference#GetMulti