# Google cloud datastore:Can I put more than 5 entities in one transaction

Tags: java, google-cloud-datastore

I followed the solution [her](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26259068/how-to-put-get-multiple-entities-at-once-in-google-cloud-datastore-using-java) to put multiple entities at once. But, I could not put more than 5 even they have the same 'kind'. as mentioned [her](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions?csw=1#Java_What_can_be_done_in_a_transaction), I can't put entities from more than 5 different entities groups (I guess entity group=kind). However, in my case all entities are belong to the same 'kind' and 'name space'. 
why I can not put more than 5 at once?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

A transaction can operate on a maximum of [5 entity groups](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/transactions#Datastore_What_can_be_done_in_a_transaction). It's the first key path component (a kind plus a name or an id) that identifies the entity group (not just the kind). For more info on entity groups, check out [this page on entities, properties, and keys](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/entities).

Comment: Is there any other way to do that, I have to enhance the performance. I need to insert large number of entities (40,000 entities or more) through my java application . when I tried to put 5 at once, Its took about one hour or more :(

Comment: If you are inserting multiple entities per entity group, you can group those together. Otherwise, you can parallelize the transactions (e.g. use threads to have multiple commits going at a time).